# How to change and set new avatar in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a problem when changing avatar in React Native.
I use react-native-router and Actions to move screen.
When I changed avatar on Profile screen. It's success. But when I come back to homepage. It doesn't change avatar because it doesn't refresh. It use old data.
Please help me by give me a solution. Thank you.

Here is Profile screen

[image]

Here is homepage

[image]

Comment: It will be more helpful if you can post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call Actions.pop({refresh: {reload:'reload'}}) componentWillReceiveProps is called on the previous scene and you may updated the current component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call method componentWillReceiveProps in homepage, something like

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (nextProps.avatar.object) {
   * here update field responsible for rendering avatar img in component*
  }
}
```